# Get attachments from SharePoint list with PowerShell

Tags: 2010, 2013, powershell

I made this script :

```
$webUrl = "http://site.fr/"    
$library = "Qualified Information"
$spSite = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webUrl)
$w = $spSite.OpenWeb()
$l = $w.Lists[$library]
$resultHashtable = @{}

foreach ($listItem in $l.Items)
{     
    Write-Host "    Content: " $listItem.ID 
    foreach ($attachment in $listItem.Attachments)
    {
        $file = $w.GetFile($listItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + $attachment)
        $linkAttachment = "http://site.fr" + $file.ServerRelativeUrl
        Write-Host "http://site.fr"$file.ServerRelativeUrl
        if($linkAttachment){
        $resultHashtable.Add($listItem.ID, $linkAttachment)
        }    
    }    
}
#Export CSV
$resultHashtable.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Name -Descending |
Select-Object -Property @{n='SiteURL';e={$_.Name}},Value |
Export-Csv -Path Attachments.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

With SharePoint 2013 it works but with SharePoint 2010, my script doesn't get the list :

> Exception calling "GetFile" with "1" argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range."

If I debug `$l`, it's null

My `Write-Host` Content: `$listItem.ID` just returns : `Content:`
My list is full of items with attachments, do you have any ideas?

Comment: what happen if you debug the $w, are you getting the correct site/web?

Answer (score 2):

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell -ErrorAction      
SilentlyContinue
$webUrl = "http://localsite"
$library = "ListName" 
#Local Folder to dump files
$tempLocation = "C:\Users\Documents\MyDownloadFolder"    
$s = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($webUrl)    
$w = $s.OpenWeb()         
$l = $w.Lists[$library]  

Write-Host "Connecting To Site: " $webUrl   

foreach ($listItem in $l.Items)
 {
  Write-Host "    Current Item ID: " $listItem.ID 

  #create folder name for each list item by using title and year column  
   value combination 

  $folderName=$listItem["Title"]+"_"+$listItem["Year"]

  $destinationfolder = $tempLocation + "\"+ $folderName  

  #check if folder is exist or not, if not exist then create new

  if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationfolder))        
   {            

     $dest = New-Item $destinationfolder -type directory      
     Write-Host "Created Folder with Name:" $folderName    
   }

  #Code to download list attachments

 if($listItem.Attachments -ne $null)
  {
   Write-Host "Downloading Attachements started: " 
  Try
   {
    foreach ($attachment in $listItem.Attachments)    
    {  
     Write-Host "Downloading Attachement: " $attachment      
     $file = $w.GetFile($listItem.Attachments.UrlPrefix + $attachment)        
     $bytes = $file.OpenBinary()                
     $path = $destinationfolder + "\" + $attachment
     Write "Saving to the loction  $path"
     $fs = new-object System.IO.FileStream($path, "OpenOrCreate") 
     $fs.Write($bytes, 0 , $bytes.Length)    
     $fs.Close()    

    }
   }
    Catch{}

  }
  else
  {
  Write-Host   "For above current item don't have any attachments" 
  }
}


     Write-Host   "Script execution done !"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using correct ListName and it exists in the Site. Try below

```
$webUrl = "http://site.fr/"    
$w = get-spweb $webUrl
$listName = "Qualified Information"
$l = $w.Lists[$listName]

write-host $l.Title
```

Comment: Are you executing this from SP 2010 Management Shell and from within the server?

Comment: PS C:\Users\devinfo\Desktop> $l = $w.Lists[$listName]
Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:15
+ $l = $w.Lists[ <<<< $listName]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Qualified Information:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray

Comment: $w.Lists is null, it didn't get any list